# How to find if a valuation satisfies a statement?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, satisfiability

I'm working on a task which i'm a bit stuck at. I need to decide whether the statements are true or fale. *F* stands for the statement logical formulas, and also if the claim is true I need to give a proof or explain why it is so. If the statement is false I need to give a contra-example

Here are the statements:

> For all F, then F is satisfiable or ¬F is satisfiable

and

> For all F, then F is valid or ¬F is valid.

Is there any easy way I can solve these kinds of statements by seeing if a statement satisfies or is valid or is neither both of them?

Would appreciate some help, thanks alot!

Comment: Do you know about truth tables?

Comment: Yes. I know how to read from truth tables

Comment: How are you defining valuation?

Comment: umm, not sure what you mean. This is the only information I have though. Do you mean the valuations in F and not F?

Comment: The rigorous definition of valuation is function with certain properties. Is any of this familiar?

Comment: No sorry, i am very new to logic =/

Comment: That's OK. I'm just trying to get some context. I think what you're asked to do is to give an informal reasoning. For the first one consider the truth table for $F$. You don't know what it looks like, but you know its lines will all be $0$ or they will not all be $0$. If they are all $0$, what can you say about the truth table for $\neg F$? If they are not all $0$, what does that tell you about $F$s satisfiability and hence about $F\lor \neg F$s satisfiability? Regarding the second one, how are you defining a 'valid statement'?

Comment: Defining a valid statement: If a statement logical formula is true for all the valuations then we say that the formula is an tautology or valid. correct?

Comment: The second one is false, then. Just consider the truth table for a single propositional atom. One of the lines is $0$ while the other is $1$ and the same happens with its negation. None of them is a tautology. I gotta go now. Hopefully someone else will give you a proper answer.

Answer (score 2):

There exist three classes of formulas: tautologies, contingencies, and contradictions.  A tautology has all "1"'s (at the end of its rows) for its truth table, a contingency has at least one "1" and at least one "0" for its truth table, and a contradiction has all "0"'s for its truth table.

Case 1:  If a formula F qualifies as a tautology, it qualifies as valid.  Thus, it always comes as satisfied, and thus always satisfiable.  So, if F qualifies as a tautology, then either F is satisfiable or $\lnot$F is satisfiable.

Case 2: If a formula F qualifies as a contingency, then its truth table has at least one row with a "1" in it.  Consequently, for that row the formula gets satisfied and thus F qualifies as satisfiable.  So, if F qualifies as a contingency, then either F is satisfiable or $\lnot$F is satisfiable.

Case 3: If a formula F qualifies as a contradiction, then it has all "0"'s in its truth table.  So, for no row does it come as satisfied.  Thus, $\lnot$F has all "1"'s for its truth table.  So, $\lnot$F always qualifies as satisfied, and thus qualifies as satisfiable.  So, if F qualifies as a contradiction, then either F is satisfiable or $\lnot$ F is satisfiable.

Since these cases exhaust the possibilities, for any given propositional formula F either F is satisfiable or $\lnot$F is satisfiable.

As Git Gud points out you only need to consider a truth table for a propositional atom for the second part.